# Check value in subclass before sending it to private superclass variable

Tags: java, inheritance

I somehow need to check the value of a variable amount being received in the subclass before sending it to the superclass.

This is what I have for my superclass

```
//superclass
public class Account 
{
    private double balance;

    public Account( double amount )
    {
            balance = amount;
    }

    public Account()
    {
            this(0.0);
    }

    public void deposit( double amount )
    {
            balance += amount;
    }

    public void withdraw( double amount )
    {
            balance -= amount;
     }

    public double getBalance()
    {
            return balance;
    }
}
```

This is what I have for my subclass

```
public class SafeAccount extends Account
{

   public SafeAccount(double amount)
   {
      // something to check if amount is positive before sending it to 
         super 

      // if it's not positive, use no argument constructor to set balance == 
         0.0
   }
}
```

I think I am supposed to use "this(amount)"  to somehow check it, but I'm not exactly sure how that will work.

Comment: This would violate [LSP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle): "*Preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype*" - may wanna rethink your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super()` must be the first statement in a constructor body so you cannot perform checks before it.

Simple work around:

```
 public class SafeAccount extends Account
{

   public SafeAccount(double amount)
   {
     super(Math.max(0.0, amount));
   }
}
```

If you really must use the no arg constructor a more complex work around would be:

```
public class Account {
    Account() {

    }

    Account(double x) {

    }
}

public class SafeAccount extends Account {
    private SafeAccount() {

    }

    private SafeAccount(double amount) {
        super(amount);
    }

    public static SafeAccount boo(double x) {
        if (x < 0.0) {
            return new SafeAccount();
        }
        return new SafeAccount(x);
    }
}
```

Use `private` constructors in your subclass to prevent instantion from constructor and supply a factory method that does the checks you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following statement

```
class SafeAccount extends Account {
    public SafeAccount(int balance) {
        super(balance > 0? balance: 0);
    }
}
```

But in general such Inheritance hierarchy needs to be rechecked for correctness of design.